# What is the tiebreaker in Wingspan if players have equal points?

Tags: wingspan

I've been playing the Android wingspan app and my previous game ended in a tie.
One of the other players was awarded the win, but I didn't see any indication of the metric used to break the tie.

What is the tie-breaker in the base game of Wingspan?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from the rules [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f2tekc23yvb27w3/AACMN8vtpP8c8G3gJ686H9xHa/Wingspan?dl=0&preview=WS_Rulebook_r23-LR.pdf&subfolder_nav_tracking=1)

> The player who has the most points wins. In the case of a tie, the
> player with the most unused food tokens wins. If players are still
> tied, they share the victory.